# Why does this happen with Longclaw?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

**Spoilers ahead for "Beyond the Wall" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E06)**

Toward the end of the episode, "Beyond the Wall" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E06), we see a close-up shot of Longclaw

> [image]

Then, once Jon Snow emerges from the water, Longclaw appears to be opening its eyes

> [image]

You can get a much better picture of it [in this imgur album, which shows the event happening, frame by frame, with comments](https://imgur.com/r/freefolk/QJ32p).

Is this an Easter Egg from the Visual Effects department, or is there an in-universe explanation behind this?

Or was this not planned at all by the production team, and this is merely a coincidental, accidental lighting/water effect, that just happens to be timed with the dramatic tension of Jon Snow possibly being dead, and the relief of him being alive?

Comment: Wow. Well noticed. Didn't catch that one.

Comment: I would guess that it may be just an Easter Egg to say that he didn't die. The wolf opens the eye meaning that: _Jon Snow is back... Once again._ The show often uses the eyes of someone opening to show someone is back. **Jon Snow's first revival. The ending of this episode and all.**

Comment: Resurecting dead people is boring, so WW decide to turn valyrian steel swords into wights. Because why not.

Comment: what a observation!! and i like your question too :) i agree with @LeonX might be possible the wolf opens the eye meaning that: Jon Snow is back... Once again.

Comment: I don't have enough proof to this, but I've seen some more convincing theories today. Some people have said that Longclaw actually have gem eyes that looks like the open eyes, and when it is completely bright, the gem is actually reflecting light giving the appearance that it is closed.

Comment: Going to go home and re-watch the episode (worth a re-watch just for that Brianne-based conversation, to be honest....)

Comment: The eyes are see through. You can see the snowy background and then you can see Jon's glove through the eyes and it moves as Jon's hand moves.

Comment: Ghost opened his eyes right before Jon came back to life. The sword is connected to Jon, just like his dire wolf. So...it opens it's eyes for Jon. a cool easter egg. It's a magical land, what can I say?I admit I didn't notice it on first viewing.

Comment: @Ankit think it's time to protect this question, low level answers from 1 rep users keep flowing in.

Answer (score 20):

This is water falling on the eyes...nothing supernatural

The Director has confirmed...

> “I haven't got a clue what they're talking about. Either this sword is magic and it’s doing stuff on its own, or something happened. I’m going to have to go back and watch that moment close up and in slow motion to see what’s going on there. I can say that there was **no intention** for that to be the case.”
>
> <sup>[Source](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2017/08/game-of-thrones-longclaw-eye-bran-warg-theory-alan-taylor-interview-beyond-the-wall)</sup>

[image]

Comment: False. If you watch it frame by frame, you will see it's clearly not water. I [uploaded large images, frame by frame, to imgur, for your convenience](http://imgur.com/a/Gyk0K), so you can see you are incorrect, here.

Comment: On VLC you can press *E* to view the next frame, it's so easy to see it isn't water. As for `supernatural`, nobody was really claiming that - it may just be an Easter Egg from the VFX department, it's not uncommon.

Comment: Here: [an album of Longclaw's eyes opening, Frame by Frame](http://imgur.com/r/freefolk/QJ32p), it's even better than the one I uploaded. You are free to ignore evidence.

Comment: @madmada What's being ignored is that it can still be an Easter Egg. It's my opinion that what we see is a gem which is conveniently lit to appear closed, and this may be an accident, but the fact that it's timed to synchronise with Jon's suspected circumstance seems, to me, to suggest that the lighting itself is something that was set up as an Easter Egg. The VFX team can then safely attribute in-universe circumstance to the water/lighting, but the fact remains that it is no accident.

Comment: That was the point I was trying to bring up. To say "Oh it's the water" and "nothing supernatural" gives the false impression that it's one or the other, when there are more possibilities (hence; false equivalence fallacy) - logical fallacies are very effective in rhetoric, especially to untrained readers/audiences, because it means the opponent has to argue on his backfoot clarifying why their arguments are not logically sound, which puts them, rhetorically, at a disadvantage, but I'm happy to continue clarifying it until the cows come home.

Comment: I agree with that. It can be both, an in universe explanation, probably water and a possible Easter Egg.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - Not sure I'm on board with the Easter Egg related to something symbolically meaningful.  If they were in that habit, Bronn would be dead after his purse o' gold fell out of reach and spilled on the battlefield (I thought for **sure** that was foreshadowing!).  :D

Comment: @GhotiandChips: Even if the frame-by-frame is not correct, that does not exclude the possibility that it is a (very minute) mistake that occurred during post-production. In realtime, the "eye" appears as a consequence from the splash of water. If the splash of water was digitally enhanced for aesthetic purposes (or entirely added after the fact, but that does not seem to be the case here), that doesn't automatically mean that there is a bigger philosophical meaning attached to it. I'm sure that you can find many minor mistakes when looking at movies frame-by-frame.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: It looks like foreshadowing, but of a different kind. Bronn has always been a sellsword with no real allegiance, but he chose the battle over the gold, thus cementing a subtle innate desire to be a knight rather than a rich man (also evidenced by him tagging along with Jaime after he's already well off, financially speaking).

Comment: @Flater see my comments on the second answer. It's pretty clear that the eyes are translucent, and you see the snow then his glove. In other scenes, the eyes take on the colour of the object behind them (usually Jons clothing). It's not a water drop.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just noticed in S6E4, first scene. Edd is about to talk to Jon before he leaves Castle Black. When Edd picks up Longclaw, the eye twinkles. No joke. If the eyes are made of some kind of polished jewel, it's bound to catch the light on occasion. However, I don't think people are wrong to make a big deal out of it.

Comment: Wow! **The producers didn't do it, real magic is happenning here!** Love this :-)

Answer (score 15):

It appears to me that the eyes are probably made of some sort of clear material, and the space between them is hollow. And what we see is John's glove through it. Watch again to see if you see it.

Comment: Actually the frame by frame does nothing to negate my suggestion. It looks exactly like what I said.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - I agree with Meg.  The darkening coincides exactly with the change in background directly behind the eyes.  Does your album require that I have the Imgur app?  Whenever I click the links in a browser it tells me it can't find the page.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Calm your farm, `Just look at this frame by frame album to see how you're wrong` sounds rude and pretentious.

Comment: @Möoz Fair enough. I deleted my comment - it wasn't meant as rude but a 1:1 representation of my reaction. Despite this being a popular answer, I strongly disagree, and all it takes is me looking at a Frame by Frame.

Comment: @GhotiandChips As much as I'd like to believe this was intentional or an Easter egg, both close up gallery's support that the glove refracts through the eye material.

Comment: Actually, after looking at images of Longclaw in different scenes I found that when held in front of Jon and his black clothing the eyes are black, and in one scene appear blue-grey over Jon's grey vest. Then, in the scene in question, the eye appears white when on snow. This seems pretty conclusive (to me, anyway) that the eyes are just translucent and refract through the pommel. Plus, the iris of a wolf is round, though one *could* argue the eyelids are part closed.

Comment: [Further evidence in this video](https://youtu.be/PyccaWD21eM?t=28s) - see the eyes as Jon unfastens the belt and we see the snow beneath his arm - the eyes are black when above his clothing but briefly white when above snow.

Comment: @Möoz - "Calm your farm" - that's a new one, to me.  I'm going to try and remember it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm just kidding here, but here is in-universe explanation I just came up with:

Wolf ornament is made of Weirwood. So when Jon was near dead, Bran felt it and connected to Longclaw to see what's going on :D

Apart from that, it's more likely water after seeing shots. It is opened exactly at the moment when water is coming down, so could be one of the first drops hit a bullseye.

Comment: The only people who claim it's water, and believe their own words, are people who haven't watched it in high-resolution, large image, frame by frame. I remain unconvinced - you have to show me that it's water, not just say it's water. When I look at it Frame by Frame, I can clearly see an eye appearing to go from closed to open - I personally think it's the way the light hits the gem, being changed for 5 frames, by the VFX team - I don't think water is a factor, I could easily tell if it were a factor.

Comment: Hm, you're right. I was looking at your shots, but looking in slow motion it really looks like eye opening. Interesting indeed.

Answer (score -3):

After this moment, when Jon tries to get out of the water with the support of Longclaw, we can see blue eyes of longclaw. When he was in the water, eyes were white. So I think it's the moment Longclaw opened it's eyes. Even in the beginning of the episode, when Jon gives it to Jorah, we can clearly see it's blue eyes.

Answer (score -3):

Kinda farfetched but maybe the crystal eyes of Longclaw is imbued with something that can detect life. I was rewatching the episode and noticed that the eyes don't open and close specifically to Jon but it was also "open" when Jorah was touching it. And since he was surrounded by death, the crystals closed?

Comment: not really an answer, most of it is speculation - unless you can back it up with some sources